How to monitor the installation of another app?
I have to monitor the installation for an anti-virus app. No receiver is working.
Any way to do it?
<receiver android:name=".core.installed_apps.AppsInstallationsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Tried this as a receiver but it is not receiving, at least PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED is not triggered.
I want to manage app installations in my application

Through your own BroadcastReceiver you can register a receiver to listen for the PACKAGE_ADDED and PACKAGE_REMOVED intents.

@BobSmith: The documentation does not agree with you.

You cannot listen for most of those broadcasts via a manifest-registered receiver. You can listen for PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED, but you need to remove the <data> element, as that broadcast does not put a Uri in the Intent. "I want to manage app installations in my application" -- it is unclear what you mean by this and whether it is practical, outside perhaps of device owner apps or custom firmware.

How about using Package Manager to check installed applications as and when required?

I can schedule packageManager to read the required apps but I will not be able to run my script as soon as I find a new installation as my scheduled time may not read it as soon as it installs.
@CommonsWare -A non owner application which will react to when a user installs any app may be google store or any 3rd party , is my goal
